# Issue with inheritance and constraints in Grails/GORM

Tags: grails, inheritance, constraints, grails-orm

Not sure how to frame this question, but I am seeing some behavior that I am unable to explain ... any help will be highly appreciated. I have a super-class `Form`, and sub-class `DraftForm`. The super-class has a more stringent constraint on a property `content(blank: false)` than the sub-class `content(nullable: true)`, and I am using `tablePerHierarchy false`. The domain classes are as follows.

```
class Form {
    String content

    static constraints = { content(blank: false) }

    static mapping = { tablePerHierarchy false }
}
```

```
class DraftForm extends Form {

    static constraints = { content(nullable: true) }
}
```

With the above domain models, the following test * passes * without any problem.

```
class DraftFormIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    void "Testing a draft-form and a form derived from a draft-form"(){

        given: "A draft-form with invalid form-fields"          // 1
        def draftForm = new DraftForm()

        when: "The draft-form is validated"                     // 2
        assert draftForm.validate() == true

        then: "The draft-form has no error"                     // 3
        !draftForm.hasErrors()

        when: "The draft-form is saved"                         // 4
        try{
            draftForm.save()
        }catch(Exception e){
            println "Exception thrown!"
            println e.class
        }

        then: "The draft-form is not found in the database"     // 5
        draftForm.id == null

        when: "The draft-form is casted to a form"              // 6
        Form form = (Form) draftForm
        assert form.validate() == true

        then: "The form validates, and has no error"            // 7
        !form.hasErrors()
    }
}
```

Here are my questions:

I think a sub-class also inherits the super-class's constraints. In that case, how come the draft form validates fine and has no error even though the `content` is `null` (please see // 2 and // 3 in the test)?

If the draft-form validates fine, why do I get an exception (// 4) and cannot find the draft-form in the database (// 5)?

When the `DraftForm` is type casted to a `Form`, it still validates fine and has no error (// 6 and // 7), even though the `content` property is still `null`. How is that possible?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `save()` return the instance or null so in your tests you need to use `assert draftForm.save() != null` or `draftForm.save(failOnError:true)`.

Comment: Thanks @Sergio. If I did `draftForm.save(failOnError: true)` without the try-catch, the test does fail by throwing an exception when it tries to save. However, I am puzzled that the `draftForm` validates without any issue (// 2) and has no error (// 3), but still I cannot save it. Although, the fact that I cannot save explains `draftForm.id == null` (// 5), but still I cannot explain how it can validate without any error but still cannot save.

Answer (score 0):

Please find answers below

As per grails doc https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html > Inheritance Strategies

**tablePerHierarchy:false** will have NOT-NULL constraint applied to **content** in **form** table at the database level, hence you got exception while saving the form object **NULL not allowed for column "CONTENT"**.

1. Yes subclass do inherits super-class constraints but for same property subclass constraints will be given priority for subclass object. Hence its validating in //2 and //3.
2. exception is due to not-null column **content** in **form** table so **NULL not allowed for column "CONTENT"** as discussed before.
3. When the DraftForm is type casted to a Form, its still an object of draftForm(**try form.class and you will see "class draft.DraftForm"**) hence got validated, if you make a new object of Form it will fail the validation as **content** would be null.

Hope this makes you understand things better.